# campos idénticos en join

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

estoy realizado una consulta en dos tablas, pero tengo dos campos iguales en las dos tabla en laravel 5.4, el poblema es como yo hago en la parte de la vista que me salga los datos un ejemplo es arboles.id y especie.id, la cuestion es que salga el id de los arboles

```
 $arbole = Arbole::where('users_id', '=', 1)->Join('especies', 'arboles.especies_idespe', '=', 'especies.id')->get();

 @foreach($listmysql as $indexKey => $lists)
                                <tr class="item{{$lists->id}} @if($lists->is_published) warning @endif">
                                    <td class="col1">{{ $indexKey+1 }}</td>
                                    <td>{{$lists->id}}</td>
                                    <!--
                                    <td>{{$lists->codigo}}</td>
                                    -->
                                    <td>{{$lists->direccion}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo lo que quieras hacer, puede variar ligeramente la solución, sin embargo la sintaxis es con `select()` en el constructor de consultas usando alias, como lo harías normalmente en sql:

```
$arbole = Arbole::where('users_id', '=', 1)
        ->join('especies', 'arboles.especies_idespe', '=', 'especies.id')
        ->select('arboles.id as id_arbole', 'especies.id as id_especie')
        ->get();
```

También podrías usar `->select('arboles.*', 'especies.id as id_especie')`

Como siempre, puedes ver más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins